# python ctypes sending pointer to structure as parameter to native library

Tags: python, pointers, struct, ctypes

I am trying to write a wrapper to a native library in Linux. Problem is this:

definition in c:

```c
int mymethod(mystruct* ptr)
```

in python:

```py
_lib.mymethod.argtypes = (ctypes.POINTER(mystruct),)                                                     
_lib.mymethod.restype = ctypes.c_int
s = mystruct()

_lib.mymethod(ctypes.byref(s))
# raises: expected LP_mystruct instance instead of pointer to mystruct

_lib.mymethod(ctypes.pointer(s))
# raises expected LP_mystruct instance instead of LP_mystruct
```

errors. How to pass a structure as a pointer to a native method ?

Thanks.

Mete

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the higher level  "POINTER" from ctypes is, in Python, a different object than "a generic pointer" (`ctypes.CArgObject` by `ctypes.byref`)which is returned   or a single number representing a memory address (which is what is returned by ctype's `adrresof`) - you can either annotate your function to receive a `` `ctypes.c_voidp `` and call it with `_lib.mymethod(ctypes.addressof(a))` instead -

Or if you want to work on the stronged-typed side to avoid errors that would crash Python (a type error raises a Python exception instead - a wrong parameter passed to a C unction would cause a segmentation fault on the Python  interpreter itself), you have to create a variable to hold the new "type" which is a POINTER to your structure - and then create an instance of this type with the address of your structure:

```
mystruct_pointer = ctypes.POINTER(mystruct)
_lib.mymethod.argtypes = (mystruct_pointer,)
_lib.mymethod.restype = ctypes.c_int

s = mystruct()

_lib.mymethod(mystruct_pointer.from_address(ctypes.addressof(s)))
```

Comment: Thanks ! I used the second method you said and it works without problem.

Comment: something similar here - https://codexample.org/questions/238108/python-ctypes-sending-pointer-to-structure-as-parameter-to-native-library.c

Comment: Which is the higher level POINTER type in ctypes ?

Answer (score 6):

(I know that this is an old question, but I think the accepted answer is an unnecessary workaround, so I want to leave this here for posterity.)

Actually ctypes should [explicitly support](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#passing-pointers-or-passing-parameters-by-reference) using `byref()` to pass a pointer like that:

> ctypes exports the `byref()` function which is used to pass parameters by reference. The same effect can be achieved with the `pointer()` function, although `pointer()` does a lot more work since it constructs a real pointer object, so it is faster to use `byref()` if you don’t need the pointer object in Python itself.

The likely cause of this is that you have defined your struct in more than one place (e.g. in different modules) - if the `argtypes` assignment sees one definition and the function call sees the other, this confusing error arises. In other words, ctypes tries to match two `mystruct` types that are (probably) identical in contents, and have the exact same name, but they are not the *same* type.  As long as the base struct type is a single type object, it doesn't matter if you construct a pointer to it using `pointer()`, `byref()` or `POINTER()()` - ctypes will detect that the underlying (pointed-to) type is the same.

To verify if this is the case, try `assert(_lib.mymethod.argtypes[0]._type_ == type(s))` right before calling the external function.